# UWP Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime"

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10

I have a full trust UWP app that uses WinUI 2.5.
Today, I updated Visual Studio to the latest version alongside WinUI (2.6 stable) and I have been getting this error message since.

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

The error is thrown by this line of code

```
 global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start((p) => new App());
```

I can see in the Package Manager the I have the version 4.0.1 of System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime package installed but there doesn't seem to be a version 4.0.3.0

Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Have you tried update the project's target and min version, it could help to repair assembly issue partly.

Comment: I tried that without success

Comment: It's hard to detect the problem without repro sample, could you try to rollback WinUI to 2.5 and test again.